# When I override the below code with products object new button it is giving me the same old new button functionality

Tags: visualforce, product

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="product2" extensions="Details" showHeader="true">
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock mode="edit">

    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputfield value="{!product2.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!product2.IsActive}"/> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!Price}" label="Product Price"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Quantity}" label="Quantity"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!product2.ProductCode}"/>  
        <apex:inputText value="{!BarcodeId}" label="Barcode Id"/>        
        <apex:inputText value="{!Categories}" label="Categories"/>     
        <apex:inputText value="{!Location}" label="Warehouse Location"/> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!Expired}" label="Expiry Date"/>  
        <apex:inputText value="{!Manufatured}" label="Manufactured Date"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!savenew}" value="Save&New"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class Details 
{
//private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public  product2 pro{get;set;}
    public string BarcodeId{get;set;}
    public string Categories{get;set;}
    public date Expired{get;set;}
    public date Manufatured{get;set;}
    public integer Price{get;set;}
    public string Quantity{get;set;}
    public string Location{get;set;}
    public Details(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        pro = new product2();
    }

    public pagereference savenew()
    {
        insert pro;
        PageReference acctPage =ApexPages.currentPage();
        acctPage.setRedirect(true);
        return acctpage;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference you see with and without override? Try changing the page and see if your changes are getting reflected.

Comment: Its same there is no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overridding add button instead of new:

[image]