# VF page goes to standard SF page, instead of custom VF page on creation of new Product2 record

Tags: visualforce

When I click "New" and then select a record type, it takes me to the standard  page layout, and not the visualforce page, it only take me to the visualforce page, when I click "cancel" on the standard page layout what is missing from my code?

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2">
<apex:sectionHeader title="R&D Project Edit" subtitle="New R&D Project" />  
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Product2.recordType.DeveloperName == 'Unavailable_R_D_Project'}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="R&D Project Detail" >
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}" label="Project Name" / >
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Directorate__c}"/>              
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Next_Stage_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.R_D_Unique_ID__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Lifecycle_Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Owner__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Alternative_Project_Contact__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Can_the_project_be_discussed_externally__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Looking_for_participants__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Description Information">
                     <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Project_Description__c}"/>
                     <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Cluster_Area_Portfolio__c}"/>
                     <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Benefits_to_the_customer__c}"/>
                     <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Eligibility__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Service Information">
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Risks__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Include_in_Dashboard__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Service__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Sector__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Alpha__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Jisc_Directorate__c}"/>
                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Date_Beta__c}"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Progress Information">
                                    <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Level_of_Demand__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Feasibility__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Notes_on_Current_Progress__c}"/>
                                    <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Expected_Usefulness__c}"/>
                                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="System Information">
                                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.createdbyId}"/>
                                            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.lastmodifiedbyId}"/>
                                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                 <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: You may need to override add button, Check this answer- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147506/when-i-override-the-below-code-with-products-object-new-button-it-is-giving-me-t/147521#147521

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any issue with your code. Salesforce.com URL is the default for the standard New button. You have to replace the  salesforce.com URL with your visualforce page in the **New** button properties to redirect. For making that change, you have to go to the Buttons, Links, and Actions for the object i.e. Product2, and **Edit** the New button. Then you can select visualforce and choose your page in the **Override properties**. I hope this answers your question.